# jQuery delegate() won't work with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently putting together some jQuery that will activate slideDown() when an element is clicked that is generated by js.

Here is my function:

```
$('.radiowrap').delegate("span[title='yes']", "click", function() { 
    $('.radiowrap').next('.secondq:first').slideDown('medium'); 
});
```

This works fine but only if I specify the element (as shown above) therefore activating every matching element. If I use $(this) like so:

```
$('.radiowrap').delegate("span[title='yes']", "click", function() { 
    $(this).next('.secondq:first').slideDown('medium'); 
});
```

The code doesn't work... does anyone have a solution to this? Here is a snippet of my HTML:

```
<div class="option radio">
    <h2 class="block">Do you have a hot water tank?</h2>
    <div class="radiowrap">
        <div class="radiocont">
            <label>Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" class="styled" value="yes" name="watertank" />
        </div>
        <div class="radiocont">
            <label>No</label>
            <input type="radio" class="styled" value="no" name="watertank" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondq" style="display:none;">
        <h2>What type of water tank is it?</h2>
        <div class="radiowrap">
            <div class="radiocont">
                <label>Steel</label>
                <input type="radio" class="styled" value="steel" name="watertanktype" />
            </div>
            <div class="radiocont">
                <label>Fibreglass</label>
                <input type="radio" class="styled" value="Fibreglass" name="watertanktype" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 align="left">How much insulation does it have?</h2>
        <input type="text" align="right" name="bonus" class="value" disabled="disabled"  />
        <div class="slidewrap">
            <div class="sliderMm slider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this` will always refer to the `span[title='yes']` element.

Comment: Just to let you, the HTML snippet you have in the question doesn't have any span tags with a title attribute of 'yes'.  However, the answer below should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$(this).closest(".radiowrap")` instead.

`.delegate()` and `.live()` try to emulate `.bind()` as close as possible; thus, inside the event handler, `this` points to the `.radiowrap span[title='yes']` that was clicked, just as if you had bound to that `<span />` directly.

Using `.closest(".radiowrap")` will find the ancestor `.radiowrap` of the clicked `<span />`, from whence you can proceed as before.